# Dealing with Scrapy Div Class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and really python as well. I am trying to write a scraper that will extract article title, link and article description ALMOST like an RSS feed from a web page to help me with my thesis. I've written the following scraper and when I run it and export it as a .txt it comes back blank. I believe I need to add in an Item Loader but I am not positive.

Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class NorthAfricaItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    desc = Field()
    pass
```

Spider

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from northafricatutorial.items import NorthAfricaItem

class NorthAfricaItem(BaseSpider):
   name = "northafrica"
   allowed_domains = ["http://www.north-africa.com/"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.north-africa.com/naj_news/news_na/index.1.html",
   ]

 def parse(self, response):
 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
 sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
 items = []
 for site in sites:
     item = NorthAfricaItem()
     item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
     item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
     item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
     items.append(item)
 return items
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Talvalin for the help and additionally with some messing around I was able to fix the problem.  I was using a stock script that I found online.  However once I utilized the shell I was able to find the correct tags to get what I needed. Ive ended up with:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from northafrica.items import NorthAfricaItem

class NorthAfricaSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "northafrica"
   allowed_domains = ["http://www.north-africa.com/"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.north-africa.com/naj_news/news_na/index.1.html",
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = NorthAfricaItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('//div[@class="short_holder"]    /h2/a/text()').extract()
       item['link'] = site.select('//div[@class="short_holder"]/h2/a/@href').extract()
       item['desc'] = site.select('//span[@class="summary"]/text()').extract()
       items.append(item)
   return items
```

If anyone sees anything here I did wrong let me know......but it works.

Comment: -----UPDATE-------   So I went back to the shell to figure out why it wasn't working.  Turns out I was using the wrong Selector.  So Now I have worked with .......... >>> hxs.select('//div[@class="short_holder"]/h2').extract() which gives me what I want but I end up with [u'<h2><a href="naj_news/news_na/2janseventeen48.html">Terror Attack on Gas Site: Algeria Faces Greatest Crisis in Decades  </a></h2>'     I'm struggling to figure out how to extract the text.  Is it a nested function?

Comment: Which selector have you modified? Could you edit your question to show the updated code please?

Comment: @Mike You should not remove your question once it is answered, it might help others with the same problem as you, instead add an update to it. I edited your question, you can roll it back if you like :)

Comment: Im still trying to figure this all out! My apologies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to note about this code is that it runs with an error. Try running the spider via the command line and you will see something along the lines of:

```
        exceptions.TypeError: 'NorthAfricaItem' object does not support item assignment

2013-01-24 16:43:35+0000 [northafrica] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The reason why this error is occurring is because you've given your spider and your item classes the same name: NorthAfricaItem

In your spider code, when you create an instance of NorthAfricaItem to assign things to (like title, link and desc), the spider version takes precedence over the item version. Since the spider version of NorthAfricaItem is not actually a type of Item, the item assignment fails.

To fix the issue, rename your spider class to something like NorthAfricaSpider and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: ah! Thank you much! I'll update and let you know. Still slightly confused as to classes and Items, etc but I'm getting two learning opportunities out of this. Thanks again.

Comment: If your code is now working as a result of the suggested correction, please upvote and mark this as the accepted answer. :)